# Adding external properties to TopoJSON file

Tags: topojson

I have TopoJSON file and want to add some external fields in it by id (and preserve old) without any other changes (like simplification or quantization) . So I used command like in the example in [TopoJSON wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/Command-Line-Reference). The command was like:

`topojson -o world-110m_ext.json -e world-country-names.tsv --id-property +id -p nameENG=name world-110m.json`.

But I got file smaller than the source and without any id properties. I tried to preserve id's like so:

`topojson -o world-110m_ext.json -p -e world-country-names.tsv --id-property +id -p nameENG=name world-110m.json`.

It did not work for me and many other ways too. What am I doing wrong?

For input I am using Mike's files from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/4090846).

Comment: Please show us sample of the relevant content of your input files.

Comment: I am using Mike's files from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/4090846)

Comment: See [How to add properties to topojson file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444261/)

Comment: I would create GeoJSONs in QGIS, use properties on them and finally convert all to TopoJSON, works great =)