# Adding external properties to TopoJSON file of counties

Tags: topojson

[related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450273/adding-external-properties-to-topojson-file)

I'm trying to add external properties to a topojson file, `us-counties.json` (made with [us-atlas](https://github.com/mbostock/us-atlas) using `make topo/us-counties.json`). I'm working off [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5562380). But my resulting topojson file `us-counties-with-population.json` has **no properties at all**.

My call looks like:

```
topojson --external-properties data.csv \
  --id-property id_county \
  --properties population=+percent_population \
  -o us-counties-with-population.json \
  -- us-counties.json
```

and my data looks like (`head -n5 data.csv`):

```
id_county,county_name,percent_population
01003,"Baldwin County, Alabama",9.71576144493279
01043,"Cullman County, Alabama",6.734653334216277
01051,"Elmore County, Alabama",7.095232589509385
01069,"Houston County, Alabama",9.857459440234194
```

*I'm using topojson v1.2.2. I think I might be missing something related to how the ids are matched, but I'm not sure what it is.*

Comment: See also : [How to add properties to topojson file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444261/)

Comment: Was a solution to this particular problem ever found? I'm running into a similar problem; I can add properties fairly easily when joining a csv with a GeoJson or shp file, but when I try to join a csv with a TopoJson, no dice. I'm rather confused.

Comment: I'm having the same problem a year later.

Answer (score 0):

Very nice question, I spent an hour on this problem spinning my wheels. It turns out the [External Properties](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/Command-Line-Reference#external-properties) section provides a simple example which uses the reference id FIPS as the id.

You should be able to use your csv with one simple modification. Rename id_county to FIPS. Next specify your external resource with the  -e flag.

```
-p name=COUNTY,name=STATE,area=+SQUARE_MIL,population=+percent_population  -e data.csv
```

Comment: This answers a separate question, which is how to make a file, merging with a csv.

Answer (score 0):

This answer worked for me: [How to add properties to topojson file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444261/how-to-add-properties-to-topojson-file?lq=1)

In your case the call would look like:

`topojson -o us-counties-with-population.json -e data.csv --id-property=id_county,id -p properties population=+percent_population -- us-counties.json`

Note: I'm assuming the `id-property` of your topojson file is `id`.